# Is there a full Siddur Nusach Eretz Yisrael?

Tags: product-recommendation, eretz-yisrael, prayer-book

Disclaimer: I do know of the Machon Shilo *Siddur Eretz Yisrael*, although according to folks I know who have studied the issue, it is not a true nusach e"y siddur.

Is there a complete siddur with the text according to Nusach Eretz Yisrael available, other than the above mentioned Machon Shilo version, either online or in print?

Comment: Nusach Eretz Yisrael is just compilations of Eretzyisraeli snippets of things AFAIK.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I was under the impression that there were large enough fragments available to accurately reconstruct the full seder tefillah. I do know that we have yotzerot for every day of the week (eg. Hakol Yoducha for Shabbat) and that shir shel yom was said in Pesukei dezimrah.

Comment: I spoke recently to Rabbi Bar Chaim. He told me the siddur that was put out some time ago called "Nusach Eretz Yisrael" was made by a talmid of his. I understand it's not the "official" siddur nusach eretz yisrael "endorsed" by Machon Shilo. As I understood it he is working on a new version that will be put out by the Machon.

Comment: what makes something nusach eretz yisrael?

Comment: @Dude, if it follows the nusach set out in the Yerushalmi and by Geonei Eretz Yisrael prior to the first crusade (when the kehilla was destroyed) it is Nusach E"Y. Much like Nusach Bavel, Nusach Ashkenaz, Nusach Sepharad, or Nusach Edot Hamizrach, there are variations.

Comment: Is there a way to get updates on when this work will be available?

Comment: @Hashamyim It'll probably be a very long time. If it ever does come out and I remember about you I'll send you a message letting you know about it.

Comment: Update on the siddur: The "Machon Shilo" Nusach Eretz Yisrael siddur isn't really from Machon Shilo. It was organized in great part by Rav Yehoshua Boch and the publication took place with the support of those involved with Machon Shilo. In terms of the machon and Rav David Bar Chaim, I would say it at best has their "support" but not full endorsement. Rav David Bar Chaim as mentioned is working on the official siddur and meanwhile davens actually from another siddur (all I could see is that it is in a spiral bound notebook form) ...

Comment: ... In terms of the future. Rav David Bar Chaim said that the official siddur that he is working on seems to be far off from publication. However those involved with the Nusach Eretz Yisrael siddur that is currently around and that was printed many years ago, it seems that those involved wish to make changes and revise that siddur and release a new one. However there is no official dates for any of this. Just what I heard first hand from the sources. The siddur from Rabbi Bar Chaim I imagine would be the best bet for the siddur of this nusach that those are looking for.

Comment: I have looked in quite a few so-called "Nusach Eretz Yisrael" siddurim and I have to say - none of these are actually Nusach Eretz Yisrael. Additionally, I don't think that Nusach Eretz Yisrael is practised by any communities in modern times.

Comment: @JoshuaPearl I think you're right. However I love looking at variant nucschaot to better understand the tefillot

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is the Nusach Eretz Yisrael siddur compiled and publisehd by Shaki.

You can also get a small mincha siddur on the OpenSiddur Project [here.](http://opensiddur.org/prayers-for/daytime/afternoon/siddur-nusah-eretz-yisrael-minha-birkat-hamazon-tefillat-haderekh/)

The best place for information about Nusach Eretz Yisrael and the Siddur is on the Hebrew [Wiki page](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97_%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C):

You can buy the new version of the [siddur here:](http://nusacheretzyisrael.weebly.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Artscroll still publishes Siddur Ner Naftali, which is available in the standard Nusachim with "adaptations for use in Israel".  What's available from Machon Shilo looks like the best, most specific option.

Comment: This is not a Nusach Eretz Yisrael siddur. See [this](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=4612) to properly understand what Nusach E''Y actually is. The siddur you linked is simply a Bavli siddur adapted for use in Israel, based on the common minhagim.

Comment: Also see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Bar-Hayim#Land_of_Israel

Comment: The Ner Naftali and the Machon Shilo are two completely different things. Putting them together in the same answer indicates two different understandings of the question, which is just confusing. Machon Shilo is trying to follow the ancient nussach of Israel, which is what the question was referring to. Artscroll is not trying to present a distinct liturgy that was present in ancient Israel, but is presenting a modern Ashkenazi text, with  couple of minor variations that have become popular in modern day Israel for whatever reason.

Comment: That being the case, you cant even say Machon Shilo is better, since they are two completely different] things.